# How to see everything registered in a given module

Tags: angularjs

During debugging it can be very useful to ask a given module "ok, so what providers *do* you know about?" Since a module is essentially an inversion of control container which you explicitly register things (factories, values, controllers, etc) into it should absolutely be possible. I can't figure out how to do it though

Comment: The `_invokeQueue` property of a module (get it e.g. as `angular.module('xxx')`) contains one entry per registered artifact (artifact := controller, directive, filter, etc). Each entry is an array, first member (string) gives you an idea of what is the artifact: `'$filterProvider'` for a filter, `'$controllerProvider'` for a controller and so on. The last member of the entry array is another array, giving you the name of the artifact at index 0. Be warned that the `_invokeQueue` property is probably intended to be private, so things can change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call .requires on the module it should tell you what dependencies it has. I do this in my unit tests to monitor them and help prevent problems if one gets deleted somehow.

```
var appModule = angular.module('yourMod'),
deps = appModule.requires;
```

The value of deps will be an array containing the dependencies of the module.

For the other parts of Angular, I believe that you can call the .has() method of the injector and see if the dependency you want has been injected into the provider. Documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector. This should be workable as most things deal with $injector.